# How to get the name of calling bat script

Tags: batch-file, call, invoke

I need to have my `2.bat` script behaviour depending on the name of calling script.

Scenario:
`2.bat` is invoked from many other external scripts, which I am not entitled to change. Only `2.bat` is under my thumb.

`1.bat`:

```
...
call 2.bat
```

`2.bat`:

```
...here place something extracting "1.bat"...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch (.bat): get the name of the first script, not the current one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087812/batch-bat-get-the-name-of-the-first-script-not-the-current-one)

Answer (score 4):

As you cant change the calling bat there will be almost impossible to get its name if it is triggered through the cmd console (may be a memory dump could help?) as then the ProcessId will hold information only for the `cmd.exe`. The command prompt history could give you some information but it would be unreliable (and requires a dump to a temporary file)

If the calling bat is double clicked you can use this:

```
 setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=2* delims= " %%a in ("%cmdcmdline%") do (
    if /i "%%~a" equ "/c" (
        for %%# in (%%~b) do (
            echo calling bat : %%~#
        )
    ) else (
        doskey /history >"%tmp%\cmd.history"
        for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%# in ("%tmp%\cmd.history") do (
            set "last_command=%%#"
        )
        echo probably this is the calling bat: !last_command!
        del /q /f "%tmp%\cmd.history"
    )
) 


pause
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the name of a calling batch with a trick.

Assuming you have a `first.bat`(you can't controll) it could look like this

```
@echo off
set caller=empty
echo This is %~0

for /L %%n in (1 1 3) do (
    echo(
    echo #1 before calling, n=%%n
    call second %%n
)

echo Back to %~0
```

And your `second.bat` detects the caller

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "func=%~0"
for /F "delims=\" %%X in ("%func:*\=%") do set "func=%%X"
if ":" == "%func:~0,1%" (
    goto %func%
)
REM *** Get the name of the caller
(
    (goto) 2>nul
    setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
    call set "caller=%%~f0"
    call set _caller=%%caller:*%%~f0=%%
    if defined _caller (
        set "callType=batch"
        call "%~d0\:mainFunc\..%~pnx0" %*
    ) ELSE (
        set "callType=cmd-line"
        cmd /c "call "%~d0\:mainFunc\..%~pnx0" %*"
    )
    echo BACK
    endlocal
)
echo NEVER REACHED
exit /b

:mainFunc
echo :mainFunc of %~nx0 arg1=%1 is called from '%caller%'/%callType%
exit /b
```

Answer (score 0):

I've adjusted jikou's and jeb's code a little bit so it can also detect the caller function from the caller script.

detectCallerScript.bat:

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "func=%~0"
for /F "delims=\" %%X in ("%func:*\=%") do set "func=%%X"
if ":" == "%func:~0,1%" (
    goto %func%
)
REM *** Get the name of the caller
(
    (goto) 2>nul
    setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
    call set "caller=%%~f0"
    call set _caller=%%caller:*%%~f0=%%
    if defined _caller (
        set "callType=batch"
        call "%~d0\:mainFunc\..%~pnx0" %%0 %*
    ) else (
        set "callType=cmd-line"
        cmd /c "call "%~d0\:mainFunc\..%~pnx0" %%0 %*"
    )
    endlocal
)
echo(NEVER REACHED
exit /b

:mainFunc
set "source=%~1"
shift /1
:mainFuncLoop
set args=%args%%1 
if "%~2" neq "" shift /1&goto:mainFuncLoop
if defined args set "args=%args:~0,-1%"
echo(:mainFunc of %~nx0 source=%source% with args="%args%" is called from '%caller%'/%callType%
exit /b
```

scriptCaller.bat:

```
@echo off
set caller=empty
echo(%~0: call detectCallerScript hi there
call detectCallerScript hi there
echo(Back to %~0
echo(
call:someFunc
exit /b

:someFunc
set caller=empty
echo(%~n0 %~0: call detectCallerScript hi there
call detectCallerScript hi there
echo(Back to %~0
echo(
```

Output:

```
scriptCaller.bat: call detectCallerScript hi there
:mainFunc of detectCallerScript.bat source=scriptCaller.bat with args="hi there" is called from '{path}\scriptCaller.bat'/batch
Back to scriptCaller.bat

scriptCaller :someFunc: call detectCallerScript hi there
:mainFunc of detectCallerScript.bat source=:someFunc with args="hi there" is called from '{path}\scriptCaller.bat'/batch
Back to :someFunc
```